# Getting textbox value with Dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Ok, I would think something like this would be incredibly simple, but apparently nothing in Dojo is simple. I'm on the verge of just dumping this thing. It's a nice idea, but I found C# and OOP easier than this. I've tried getting the value of the AddressModel_ZipCode textbox multiple ways now. Every time I am pulling null on it. I've also tried using dom-attr to no avail. Can anyone see where the hell I'm going wrong here? Thanks.

```
 require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/request"],
function (dom, domStyle, request) {
    window.getZipCode = function () {
        var zipcode = dom.byId("AddressModel_ZipCode");
        alert(zipcode.get("value"));
        request.post("../PricingRequest/custinfozip", {
            data: { zipCode: zipcode }
        }).then(function (response) {
            dom.byId('custinfozip').innerHTML = response;
            var zipErrorMessage = dom.byId('zipErrorMessage');
            if ('@Model.AddressModel.ErrorMessage' != null) {
                domStyle.set(zipErrorMessage, 'display', 'inline');
            }
            else {
                domStyle.set(zipErrorMessage, 'display', 'none');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Show the HTML snippet where the form is appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the people over at dojo helped me. If you're using dojo and not dijit then it's dom.byId('node').value. I had other problems screwing me up too as a result of firefox so I take back what I said about dojo. lol

Comment: Plus 1 for helping me with getting the value of a field!